# Provenance of the Apollo 11 landing presented in a NASA PR film

Tags: apollo-11, historical-data

"The Eagle Has Landed: The Flight of Apollo 11" is the title of an 18 minute NASA public relations film from 1969, available through the [National Archives Catalog](https://catalog.archives.gov/id/45017). One section shows the view from the Eagle approaching the landing, accompanied by what appears to be genuine voice transmissions. However the timescale is apparently highly  compressed - here's an altitude loss of 16,800 feet in 25 seconds (transcript taken from [here](https://www.archives.gov/files/social-media/transcripts/transcript-eagle-has-landed-1969-45017.pdf) and agrees with my listening)

(video offset time 09:56)

> Ed Aldrin: 
>     Altitude now 21,000 feet.  Still looking very good.  Velocity down now to 1200 feet per second.
>
> CAPCOM:
>     You’re looking great to us Eagle.
>
> Neil Armstrong: 
>     Give us a reading on the 1202 program alarm.
>
> CAPCOM:
>     Roger we got – we’re a Go on that alarm.
>
> Ed Aldrin: 
>     Good radar data.  We’re now in the approach phase.  Everything looking good. Altitude 4,200...

(video offset time 10:22)

It's not surprising that the landing is truncated to meet the needs of a short educational film, but some of the text such as "we're now in the approach phase" doesn't appear in the Apollo 11 transcripts I've found elsewhere, such as http://apollo11.spacelog.org/page/04:04:35:26/.

What's the provenance of this film - e.g. did NASA have the astronauts record additional dialog to "make a long story short", or use recordings from training sessions, etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lines:

> Altitude now 21 thousand feet. Still looking very good. Velocity down now to 12 hundred feet per second.

and

> We're now in the approach phase of it, looking good. Altitude 52 hundred feet

were spoken, verbatim, during the Apollo 11 landing, but not by Aldrin; according to the [PAO Mission Commentary transcript](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/AS11_PAO.PDF) both were spoken by the NASA Public Affairs Office commentator.

Interpolating from the [Apollo Flight Journal transcript](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.landing.html), which doesn't include PAO, these calls must have been at about mission time 102:40 and 102:42.

Combining the two sources, we get something like:

> 102:39:48 Aldrin: AGS and PGNS look real close.
>
> 102:39:50 Armstrong (onboard): Okay. (Pause) (Garbled) No flags. RCS is good. DPS is good. Pressure...Okay. [Cabin recording, not air-to-ground, so not in PAO transcript]
>
> [PAO "Altitude now 21 thousand feet. Still looking very good. Velocity down now to 12 hundred feet per second."]
>
> 102:40:08 Duke: At 7 minutes, you're looking great to us, Eagle.

and

> 102:41:51 Duke: Eagle, you're looking great. Coming up 9 minutes. (Pause)
>
> [PAO "We're now in the approach phase of it, looking good. Altitude 52 hundred feet"]
>
> 102:42:05 Armstrong: Manual attitude control is good.

So that's a 16800 foot drop in roughly 120 seconds; the 1200 fps figure in the first call is mostly horizontal velocity.

Armstrong's "give us a reading on the 1202" and Capcom's response are out of sequence in your transcript, coming at 102:38:42-102:38:53.